# CircleCI run failed on delete k8s resource

Tags: kubernetes, circleci

I have CircleCI setup and running fine normally, it will helps with creating deployment for me. Today I have suddenly had an issue with the step in creating the deployment due to an error related to kubernetes.

I have the config.yml followed the doc from https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/circleci/kubernetes

Here is my version of setup in the config file:

```
version: 2.1

orbs: 
  kube-orb: circleci/kubernetes@1.3.0

commands:
  docker-check:
    steps: 
      - docker/check:
        docker-username: MY_USERNAME
        docker-password: MY_PASS
        registry: $DOCKER_REGISTRY

jobs: 
  create-deployment:
    executor: aws-eks/python3
    parameters: 
      cluster-name:
        description: Name of the EKS cluster
        type: string
    steps:
      - checkout
      # It failed on this step
      - kube-orb/delete-resource:
        now: true
        resource-names: my-frontend-deployment
        resource-types: deployments
        wait: true
```

Below is a copy of the error log

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
#!/bin/bash
RESOURCE_FILE_PATH=$(eval echo "$PARAM_RESOURCE_FILE_PATH")
RESOURCE_TYPES=$(eval echo "$PARAM_RESOURCE_TYPES")
RESOURCE_NAMES=$(eval echo "$PARAM_RESOURCE_NAMES")
LABEL_SELECTOR=$(eval echo "$PARAM_LABEL_SELECTOR")
ALL=$(eval echo "$PARAM_ALL")
CASCADE=$(eval echo "$PARAM_CASCADE")
FORCE=$(eval echo "$PARAM_FORCE")
GRACE_PERIOD=$(eval echo "$PARAM_GRACE_PERIOD")
IGNORE_NOT_FOUND=$(eval echo "$PARAM_IGNORE_NOT_FOUND")
NOW=$(eval echo "$PARAM_NOW")
WAIT=$(eval echo "$PARAM_WAIT")
NAMESPACE=$(eval echo "$PARAM_NAMESPACE")
DRY_RUN=$(eval echo "$PARAM_DRY_RUN")
KUSTOMIZE=$(eval echo "$PARAM_KUSTOMIZE")
if [ -n "${RESOURCE_FILE_PATH}" ]; then
    if [ "${KUSTOMIZE}" == "1" ]; then
    set -- "$@" -k
    else
    set -- "$@" -f
    fi
    set -- "$@" "${RESOURCE_FILE_PATH}"
elif [ -n "${RESOURCE_TYPES}" ]; then
    set -- "$@" "${RESOURCE_TYPES}"
    if [ -n "${RESOURCE_NAMES}" ]; then
    set -- "$@" "${RESOURCE_NAMES}"
    elif [ -n "${LABEL_SELECTOR}" ]; then
    set -- "$@" -l
    set -- "$@" "${LABEL_SELECTOR}"
    fi
fi
if [ "${ALL}" == "true" ]; then
    set -- "$@" --all=true
fi
if [ "${FORCE}" == "true" ]; then
    set -- "$@" --force=true
fi
if [ "${GRACE_PERIOD}" != "-1" ]; then
    set -- "$@" --grace-period="${GRACE_PERIOD}"
fi
if [ "${IGNORE_NOT_FOUND}" == "true" ]; then
    set -- "$@" --ignore-not-found=true
fi
if [ "${NOW}" == "true" ]; then
    set -- "$@" --now=true
fi
if [ -n "${NAMESPACE}" ]; then
    set -- "$@" --namespace="${NAMESPACE}"
fi
if [ -n "${DRY_RUN}" ]; then
    set -- "$@" --dry-run="${DRY_RUN}"
fi
set -- "$@" --wait="${WAIT}"
set -- "$@" --cascade="${CASCADE}"
if [ "$SHOW_EKSCTL_COMMAND" == "1" ]; then
    set -x
fi
kubectl delete "$@"
if [ "$SHOW_EKSCTL_COMMAND" == "1" ]; then
    set +x
fi

error: exec plugin: invalid apiVersion "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1"

Exited with code exit status 1
CircleCI received exit code 1
```

Does anyone have idea what is wrong with it? Im not sure whether the issue is happening on Circle CI side or Kubernetes side.

Comment: where is the error ?

Comment: So the this error log is shown on CircleCI's app, and the error message is `error: exec plugin: invalid apiVersion "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1`

Comment: seems like a version mismatch, start by downloading the new `kubectl` binary, set up its path and retry.  it may help if the issue is caused by old kubectl. Else you may need to see the logs, errors, and other debugging means to identify the error.

Comment: I see, let me try to download the new kubctl binary and see how far it goes from there. Thanks for the advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the exact issue since yesterday morning (16 hours ago). Then taking @Gavy's advice, I simply added this in my `config.yml`:

```yaml
steps:
  - checkout
  # !!! HERE !!!
  - kubernetes/install-kubectl:
      kubectl-version: v1.23.5
  - run:
```

And now it works. Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried your approach and it's still giving me the same error, Im seeing people are saying v1.23.6 works, but I saw from https://gist.github.com/Zheaoli/335bba0ad0e49a214c61cbaaa1b20306 that as long as it's a version less than 1.24.0 should be fine, so I guess it wouldn't matter whether its 1.23.5 or 1.23.6, but I haven't tried 1.23.6 yet tho

Comment: @user14459580 I'm not sure if it will make a difference, but I've just noticed I'm using the `cimg/base:stable` docker image + `circleci/aws-cli@3.1.1` orb instead of `aws-eks/python3` executor.

Comment: so the issue got fixed after removing the version specification under `install-kubectl` in our case. I think yours is also a solution for it with another case, so i will mark it as the answer.